# get main part of url including virtual directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, url, request

I am working with .net 4.0 c#.

I want to be able to get the url from the current http request, including any virtual directory. So for example (request and sought value):

http://www.website.com/shop/test.aspx -> http://www.website.com/shop/

http://www.website.com/test.aspx -> http://www.website.com/

http://website.com/test.aspx -> http://website.com/

How is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is what I use

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath;
```

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath won't return /shop/ in their first example if it's not the root of the application.

Comment: It's a good point IF 'shop' is not a virtual directory.  I guess I went with the assumption that it was based on amateur's question.  So the question then becomes does amateur want the full path to the root of the application (what my code provides) or just the full url minus the file name.

Comment: Now that I re-read the question, they do just say virtual directory,  So your answer does fit the question specifically.

Answer (score 4):

Request.Url should contain everything you need. At that point it's a matter of checking the string, and what you prefer to grab from it. I've used AbsoluteUri before, and it works.

This example isn't fool proof, but you should be able to figure out what you need from this:

```
string Uri = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
string Output = Uri.Substring(0, Uri.LastIndexOf('/') + 1 );
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution could work and is shorter:

```
string url = (new Uri(Request.Url, ".")).OriginalString;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
Request.Url.OriginalString.Substring(0, Request.Url.OriginalString.LastIndexOf(Request.FilePath.Substring(Request.FilePath.LastIndexOf("/")))) + "/"
```